# Changing Password - Update SQLite Database - No Such Column

Tags: java, android, sql, eclipse, sqlite

I've written a class that I want to change the password of the user. I have it all set up fine apart from the fact that it says No Such Column, even though I've input data into the database that matches it, and 'C3438525' is used for login (which works successfully showing it's in the database fine)

I've tried using several different formats of SQL statement but no results

Here is the class, if any others are needed please ask and I'll paste them.

**changePassword.java**

```
public class changePassword extends Activity {  

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB;
    DB db = new DB(this);   
    //Load session name 
    String sessionName;
    String sessionPassword;
    String currentPasswordString;
    String newPassword1String;
    String newPassword2String;
    //Load text fields
    EditText currentPassword;
    EditText newPassword1;
    EditText newPassword2;  

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.changepassword);
        Button changePassword = (Button)findViewById(R.id.changePasswordButton);
        //Load session name
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("temp", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
        sessionName = preferences.getString("sessionName", ""); 
        sessionPassword = preferences.getString("sessionPassword", ""); 
        currentPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.currentPassword);
        newPassword1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newpassword1);       
        newPassword2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newpassword2);   
    }

    //Mismatched password checking
    public void updatePassword(View v)
    {       
        currentPasswordString = currentPassword.getText().toString();
        newPassword1String = newPassword1.getText().toString();
        newPassword2String = newPassword2.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(changePassword.this, sessionName.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(changePassword.this, newPassword2String.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (currentPasswordString.equals(sessionPassword))
        {
            if (newPassword1String.equals(newPassword2String))
            {
            checkDB = db.getWritableDatabase();
            checkDB.execSQL("UPDATE Students SET Student_Password=" + newPassword2String + " WHERE CNumber= " + sessionName);
            Log.d("Password", "Changed");
            }
        }
    }
```

LogCat:

```
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144): Process: com.example.project, PID: 2144
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     ... 11 more
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: C3438525 (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE Students SET Student_Password=1234 WHERE CNumber=C3438525
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at com.example.project.changePassword.updatePassword(changePassword.java:64)
04-09 10:40:23.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: Set '..' around the sessionName in the UPDATE statement

Comment: And also around `newPassword2String`

Comment: Did you try uninstalling again?

Comment: @Rasel It has nothing to do with adding a new colum. It's just a common SQL syntax error.

Comment: do not initiate your variables outside of methods:
    DB db = new DB(this);  instead move it to your onCreate() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some options:

- Try adding single quotes to the value in the SQL statement, like:

... SET Student_Password='1234' WHERE ...

- You may have recently done changes to the database schema, try increasing by one the database version inside the DBHelper (or reinstalling the app in the device you are using).
- Check the create statement and verify the column name and type.